# Capture Function keys on Mac OS X

Tags: swift, macos, keyevent

I'm a long-time Objective-C user and slowly migrating towards Swift with new projects. I'm using CocoaPods for the bigger things and can't find a good library to cover this.

So I have this code inside my NSViewController `viewDidLoad` to start with:

```
_ = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask) {
    (event) -> Void in
    print("Event is \(event)")
}

let event = NSEvent.keyEventWithType(NSEventType.KeyDown,
                                     location: CGPoint(x:0,y:0),
                                     modifierFlags: NSEventModifierFlags(rawValue: 0),
                                     timestamp: 0.0,
                                     windowNumber: 0,
                                     context: nil,
                                     characters: "\n",
                                     charactersIgnoringModifiers: "",
                                     isARepeat: false,
                                     keyCode: 0) //NSF7FunctionKey
NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendEvent(event!)
```

So the first event capturing works perfect after having my app checked in the System Preferences' Accessibility list. Anywhere in OS X it will capture key-presses. Now in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSEventType) it says for Function-keys I should use `keyEventWithType`.

I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Serneum/b0ed0f75f3d0c6e4058a) and noticed that it addresses the same `sharedApplication` instance, yet I don't know how to catch the event. Do I delegate in a certain way? Also the F-key constant is `int` and the method says it only wants to receive `Uint16`. I can typecast it, but I guess I'm using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using a CocoaPods [pod](https://github.com/nhurden/MediaKeyTap) that I found later. Works perfectly.